# How to make correctly in VB NET function to refresh data from SQL Server in some interval (timer)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, timer

I have a some code for checking data from sql server every 5 sec.
It is actually good, but I see that memmory usage is growing slowly? What can cause this?

It is simple code:
Public LastID as integer=0
Public NewID as integer=0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerSken.Tick

```
    Dim com As New SqlCommand("Select * from Products  where datediff(second,FinishedDate, GETDATE())<7 order by ID desc", Connection)
    Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
    Dim tableTimer As New DataTable()
    ad.Fill(tableTimer)

    If tableTimer.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Return
    End If

    NewID = tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("ID")

    If LastID <> NewID Then

        Dim Tittle As String = tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("Operator").ToString & ", " & tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("FinishedDate").ToString
        Dim text As String = tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("Customer").ToString & ", " & tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("WorkID").ToString & vbNewLine & tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("Product").ToString & ", " & tableTimer.Rows.Item(0)("Operation").ToString
        LastID = NewID

        Notification.Show(Me, info.Caption = Tittle, info.Text = text)
    End If

End Sub
```

Is it ok that all this I put inside timer?

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are using? Cheers!

Comment: Why are you creating a `DataTable` and then not using it?

Comment: Ah.. sorry. I simplified code manually. Correct is TableTimer.. my mistake.